# Append text on a link element with href ending in a specific value, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I have found answers that help with this situation but not specifically do what I am trying to.

Testing to see if an `<a>` element's `href` ends in a certain string value using an if statement. Specifically ending in ".pdf" then appending the text "(PDF)" to that link text.

I know that you can use:

```
$( "a[href$='.pdf']" ).text( "THIS IS A PDF LINK" );
```

But, this will overwrite the link text. I also have to do this on many elements so

```
var original = $("li a[href$='.pdf']").text();
var toAppend = " (.PDF)";
$("li a[href$='.pdf']").text(original + toAppend);
```

will not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using this will work :

```
$("li a[href$='.pdf']").append(' (PDF)');
```

`.append()` will, in this case, append a text node : http://jsfiddle.net/2daMW/

Comment: Wow perfect! This is way simpler than I expected. Did not realize there was a `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
$('li a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function() {
    var original = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(original + ' (.PDF)');
});
```